# Producing a 1-2 minute delayed stream from input udp stream with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, udp

With reference to following thread:

[Producing a udp stream delay with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1163109/producing-a-udp-stream-delay-with-ffmpeg/1360142#1360142)

I need to produce a 1-2 minute delayed stream from input udp stream with ffmpeg.

@Gyan so will that append live stream after blackstream ? or that will just cut live stream so after first stream is completed, actual will start from current time and without actual delayed?

Or that will be actually delayed stream of Input stream?

Like if actual live stream time is currently 00:05:30 and output of UDP delayed stream at that time is let say 00:04:30 , if we set N=60 in above command?

Can you please guide?